# Perl Breaking out of an If statement

Tags: perl, if-statement, break, control-flow

This one just came up: How do I break out of an `if` statement? I have a long if statement, but there is one situation where I can break out of it early on.

In a loop I can do this:

```
while (something ) {
    last if $some_condition;
    blah, blah, blah
    ...
}
```

However, can I do the same with an if statement?

```
if ( some_condition ) {
    blah, blah, blah
    last if $some_other_condition; # No need to continue...
    blah, blah, blah
    ...
}
```

I know I could put the `if` statement inside a block, and then I can break out of the block:

```
{
    if ( some_condition ) {
        ...
        last if $some_other_condition; # No need to continue...
        blah, blah, blah
        ...
    }
}
```

Or, I can create a subroutine (which is probably better programmatically):

```
if ( some_condition ) {
    run_subroutine();
}

sub run_subroutine {
    blah, blah, blah
    return if $some_other_condition;
    blah, blah, blah
    ...
}
```

But is there any way to exit an `if` condition?

---

### Resolution

The question came up because I was helping someone with their code. Inside a fairly long `if` statement, there were several other `if` statements embedded in it. The code looked something like this:

```
 if ( $condition1 ) {
    blah, blah, blah;
    if ( not $condition2 ) {
       blah, blah, blah;
       if ( not $condition3 ) {
          blah, blah, blah;
       }
    }
}
```

I thought the whole thing could be made more readable by doing this:

```
if ( $condition1 ) {
    last if $condition2;
    blah, blah, blah;
    last if $condition3;
    blah, blah, blah;
}
```

This shows that the normal flow of the `if` statement is standard, but under certain conditions, the `if` statement was exited early -- much like using `last` or `next` in a `while` or `for` loop to exit the loop.

I liked [mpapec's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053749/368630) solution of using a label -- even if I don't use the label itself. The label is a description of my `if`:

```
IF-UNDER-CONDITION1:
{
    if ( $condition1 ) {
        last if $condition2;
        blah, blah, blah;
        last if $condition3;
        blah, blah, blah;
    }
}
```

Although it isn't a standard coding technique, the flow of the code is obvious enough that a typical low-level Perl developer (the one that has to maintain this code after I leave) could figure out what the code is doing and maintain it. They may even learn something in the process.

Comment: Create a "block" inside the if statement and break out of that.

Comment: `goto` a label at the end.  Otherwise, no.

Comment: The question suggests better program design.  `if` is not meant to break early, if that is needed, you need another program construct (eg function call, another `if`, a `label`) or remove the expressions from your if block.

Comment: @vol7ron this is in it's nature similar to `next`, or `last` inside while loop. Alternative is more code with `if` blocks and more code indentation.

Comment: @mpapec right, `next` and `last` are really used for iteration control and abused by block-control.  `if` is a logic control and is not designed to *exit early*.  If there's other logic, then you should use other `if`, or other parts to the language.

Comment: @vol7ron and how about early returns from subroutines?

Comment: @mpapec subroutines are expected to execute one or more statements **and** return a value.  `if` is logical flow, expected to execute statements - if there are statements that aren't supposed to be executed, then another logic condition should be used.

Comment: @vol7ron structured programming apologists may say same thing for early return from subroutines

Comment: what's wrong with putting the `if` inside a block? You can label the block if you're concerned about it looking weird.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [basic block](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Basic-BLOCKs) which is subject to `last`, `next` and `redo`, so there is possible break from it.

```
if ($condition) {EXIT_IF:{

   last EXIT_IF; # break from code block

   print "never get's executed\n";
}}
```

---

```
EXIT_IF: {
  if ($condition) {

     last EXIT_IF; # break from code block

     print "never get's executed\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `last` to get out of `do {}`.

Comment: That's an interesting solution. I can't use `do`, but it works without a do. Looks a wee bit strange in a if/else situation because the if has double `{{`, but not the `else`.

Comment: @mpapec I've been programming Perl since 3.x, and it never occurred to me before. I was helping someone with their program. They had a long `if` statement and half way through, they had another condition that if met would stopped executing the last half of the `if`. I thought it looked ugly, and added too many indents to the code. I was about to suggest using `last` when I suddenly dawned on me that `last` doesn't work in `if` statements.

Comment: IMO the last version here is the best given in any answer (only with proper indentation)

Comment: @mpapec - I decided to use a variation of your last method. My label is a description of the if statement, and I simply used `last`. The label doesn't do anything, but acts as a handy description. I'll probably have the whole block rewritten to use a subroutine instead. The if takes up over 40 lines of code which is just too long in my opinion.

Comment: @DavidW.  Labels being good and all (I use labeled blocks freely and often) i actually like it better here without one:  `if ($cond) {{ ... last if $other; ... }} else { ... }`.  Kinda clean, with minimal added syntax

Comment: It makes sense for small scopes.

Answer (score 4):

- Put it inside an empty `for()` loop, and add `last;` everywhere you want to break out AND after the `if`. A bit ugly but works. Make sure to add comments to explain the trick.

  ```
  for (;;) {
      if (condition) { 
          #code
          last if another_condition;
      }
      last;
  }
  ```
- use [`goto`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html) and label a statement after your loop for that goto. Be forever damned.
- Extra block inside the `if` (e.g. `if () {{ code }}`). May be hard to read for novices but OK if accompanied by a comment.
- your own solution: block around `if`. Not very obvious readability-wise.
- your own solution: subroutine with return.

  Frankly, unless the cost of calling a sub matters performane wise, **this is the cleanest solution as far as readability**.

Comment: you mean just an empty block, not a `for (;;)`, which is an endless loop

Comment: Not a good solution. What happens when I finish my if statement? I end up looping back through my `if` again. I now have to put another `last` statement in my `if`. My OP when I put an empty block is cleaner.

Comment: Using `for` for no reason is less legible than just adding a `{}` block somewhere.

Comment: @ysth - I just forgot the last "last" in the code example. Fixed

Comment: @DavidW. - sorry, the example forgot the "last" at the end.

Comment: @aschepler - "{{" is hard to visually distinguish from "{" for those who don't know this trick. "for" at least jumps out at you, even if you need a comment to explain what it's for. Neither is, of course, as optimal as having a subroutine readability wise

Comment: so put the block around the if so there's no {{

Comment: @ysth - that was option #4. I listed ALL options I was aware of.

Comment: hmm, I don't see how that is less readable; certainly using an explicit label would be a good idea

Answer (score 2):

You could put the rest of your `if` block inside another `if` statement, like this:

```
if (some_condition) {
    blah, blah, blah
    if (!$some_other_condition) {
        blah, blah, blah
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that. You can do the same thing with `while` and `for` loops too, but the `last` and `next` help clean up the loop logic.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use an anonymous subroutine.
***Note:*** I don't recommend this method because of the added scoping complexity (see note below); it is just for completeness of possible answers.

```
if( $true_condition ){
   (sub{
       return if $true_condition;
       ...
   })->();
}
```

***Note:** any variables declared w/in the routine must use `our` instead of `my` if you wish to use them in the rest of the code.*

Comment: I don't think any nontrivial perl questions can be completely answered.

Comment: regarding "our vs my" note, same rules would apply as if there is some other code block instead of anon func.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use sequential if-statements based on a "do I continue?" variable instead.  Your

```
if ( $condition1 ) {
  blah, blah, blah;
  if ( not $condition2 ) {
     blah, blah, blah;
     if ( not $condition3 ) {
        blah, blah, blah;
     }
  }
}
```

can be rearranged to

```
my $ok = $condition1;
if ($ok) {
  blah, blah, blah;
  $ok = not $condition2;
}
if ($ok) {
  blah, blah, blah;
  $ok = not $condition3;
}
if ($ok) {
  blah, blah, blah;
}
```

Comment: It's interesting and is simple. My only concern is that the setting of `ok` depends upon each and every `if` condition. MY fear is that someone looking over the program will see the first `my $ok = ...` statement, but miss the others that are embedded in the `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `while` loop so you can use `last` *but also* make sure that the loop is executed at most once

```
my $loop_once = 1;
while ( $loop_once-- and some_condition ) {
    blah, blah, blah
    last if $some_other_condition; # No need to continue...
    blah, blah, blah
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by [DVK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17053712/2877364) to play around, and I came up with this variant that works at least on Perl 5.26.1:

```
for( ; some_condition ; last ) {
    blah, blah, blah
    last if $some_other_condition; # No need to continue...
    blah, blah, blah    
}
```

Per [`perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops), this is equivalent to:

```
while (some_condition) {
    blah, blah, blah
    last if $some_other_condition; # No need to continue...
    blah, blah, blah    
} continue {
    last;
}
```

In a [`continue`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/continue.html) block, `last` has the same effect as if it had been executed in the main loop.  Therefore, the loop will execute zero or one times, depending on `some_condition`.

#### Tests

```
perl -E 'my ($cond, $other)=(X, Y); 
         for(;$cond;last) { say "hello"; last if $other; say "goodbye" }'
```

has the following results, for various `X` and `Y` values:

```
X Y   Prints
-----------------------
0 0   (nothing)
0 1   (nothing)
1 0   hello, goodbye
1 1   hello
```